# Why is Button Value Attribute not displaying?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The only button I have assigned a value attribute at this point is "AC" until I can figure out why it is not working. When AC is pushed the value 89 should display to the screen but currently nothing is happening.

Here is my pen:

http://codepen.io/roryavant8/pen/BjPRMW

HTML:

```
<div id="calculator">
  <center>
    <div id="resultBar">
  </center>
  <div class="row">
    <button type ="button" value="89">AC</button>
    <button>CE</button>
    <button>%</button>
    <button>/</button>
  </div>
  <!----Closing rowOne div-->
  <div class="row">
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
    <button>*</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
    <button>-</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button>.</button>
    <button>0</button>
    <button>Ans</button>
    <button>=</button>
  </div>
  </div><!-----Closing Calculator div--->
```

JavaScript/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(button).click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('value'));

  });
});
```

Comment: There's a typo:) `$(button)` should be `$('button')`

Answer (score 6):

`button` is a selector not a variable holding a selector. You will need a single quote.

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function(){
      alert($(this).attr('value'));

    });
});
```

Working fork: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrLzQr

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Text is to getting the text of button.

If you are giving value, then only you will get value
Eg :

```
<button value = "7">7</button>
<!-- In this case, you can write to get value. -->
alert($(this).attr('value'));
```

If value attribute is not present, it gives "undefined" as output.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).val())
 });
});
```